# Matplotlib annotations are out of place on polar graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, annotations, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to add in some annotations on polar projected matplotlib ax objects. Most of the annotations are pretty long (40 +/- 3 characters).
**Is there a way to have more control of these longer annotations on a polar projection?**  By more control, I mean closer to the line.

```
# This annotation works alright
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection="polar")
ax.axvline(x=np.pi/3, color="black", alpha=0.618)
ax.annotate("this ok", xy=[np.pi/3,0.75], rotation=np.rad2deg(np.pi/3))

# This one doesn't work
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection="polar")
ax.axvline(x=np.pi/3, color="black", alpha=0.618)
ax.annotate("this doesn't work b/c it's pretty long", xy=[np.pi/3,0.75], rotation=np.rad2deg(np.pi/3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the annotating text is rotated. Thereby the upper left corner of the rectangle that surrounds the complete text (called bounding box) is far away from the text. This upper left corner however is the point which sits by default at the coordinates that are specified with the `xy` argument to `ax.annotate()`. This can be seen in the left plot below.

The solution is to use the lower left point of the surrounding rectangle instead and move it somewhere close to the origin. Using the lower left corner can be done by specifying `ha="left"` (horizontal alignment), `va="bottom"`.

```
ax2.annotate("this does work b/c we specifiy alignment", 
            xy=[0,0.07], rotation=np.rad2deg(np.pi/3),
            ha="left", va="bottom")
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

try setting the font sizes smaller so it fits

```
SIZE = 8
MED_SIZE = 10
BIG_SIZE = 12
plt.rc('axes',titlesize=SIZE) #fontsize of the axes titles is set to 8
```